# FormGroup and Stepper Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a question, is it possible to add 2 "new FormControl" on the same [stepControl]?
Let me explain, in my application when I'm in step 2 of my stepper, to go to step 3 I have to enter a date:

```
***<mat-step [stepControl]="dateControl">***
      <h3>Select date</h3>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" (dateInput)="test()" (dateChange)="test()" formControlName="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>

      <section class="example-section">
        <h3>Select time</h3>
        <mat-radio-group *ngFor="let time of availableHours;  let i = index" formControlName="time" required>
          <!-- <button formControlName="time" mat-fab color="primary" value="time" (click)="getTime(time)">{{ time }} - {{ time + 1 }} h. </button> -->
          <mat-radio-button class="example-margin" [checked]="selected === i" (change)="selected = i" value="{{time}}">{{ time }} - {{ time + 1 }} h.</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </section>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperPrevious type="button">Retour</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext type="button">Suivant</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
```

But I would also like to add the fact of choosing a time (everything is ok, I get the time) but I can go to step 3 of my stepper without choosing an hour because I have only one "[stepControl]="dateControl"".
Is it possible to add 2 formControl on one stepControl ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to create a [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#choosing-reactive-or-template-driven-forms) Angular [FormGroup](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#add-a-formgroup) that contains both your date FormControl and your time FormControl (and with them, each of their validators or list of validators) and replace `dateControl` in the `[stepControl]` assignment with the name of your FormGroup.

By doing this it should require that all the validators for both FormControls in the FormGroup must be valid before allowing the stepper to proceed.

If `dateControl` is already created as a new FormGroup, all you really need to do is add the time FormControl into the code that builds the FormGroup so their will be two FormControls in the group.

You could rename it as `dateTimeControl` for clarity or copy the old FormGroup and give it that new name so you can switch back and forth between the new and old FormGroup in the template code while you test the fix.

I've not used Angular Material or its stepper component but both the Angular FormControl and FormGroup extend AbstractControl and should be usable in the same context that evaluates validity for any AbstractControl instance.

[This 'reactive' FormGroup validation tutorial step](https://toddmotto.com/reactive-formgroup-validation-angular-2#what-is-a-formgroup) illustrates creating a FormGroup and how the validators can be added.

[This possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479458/angular-material-2-mathorizontalstepper-form-validation) with a really uninformative question title could also provide helpful related guidance as the answer is similar to what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

The `[stepControl]` on a `mat-step` can be any `AbstractControl`. To nest values in a single control you can use a `FormGroup`.

```
datesGroup = new FormGroup({
  startDate: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  endDate: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});
```

Html:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="datesGroup">
  <form [formGroup]="datesGroup">
    <input matInput formControlName="startDate">
    <input matInput formControlName="endDate">
  </form>
</mat-step>
```

The `datesGroup` will only be valid if all its nested controls are valid and so in the above example the step will only be completed once all values are entered.